# What are possible reasons why Tooltwist Controller generates an incomplete JSP page?

Tags: jsp, tooltwist

With the generated jsp file, looks like the widget's `getCodeInserters()` method was not called. The widget's helper initialization, page imports, inline css/js were missing from the jsp. The widget's renderForJSP() method was called based on log below.

This widget is part of a zone, and the same thing happened to all the widgets included in the zone. All the pages that use that zone throw the same error as below.

No widgets nor designer changes were pushed to production. All the child widgets of that zone have no database dependency during page generation.

Issue happens on a particular build, but then the next build generates the correct jsp.

```
    ...
    An error occurred at line: 1,487 in the jsp __file: /navpoint/xx-home.jsp
    productionHelper_xall_layouts_headers_and_footers_headerxx2_405 cannot be resolved to a variable

    ....
    1484: <td ><%-- Widget mall.layouts.headers.and.footers.headerxx2@405 (type=xx.eyyyyyrce.feedbackform.zzztrollzz.FeedbackFormWidgetController) --%>  
    1485: <%  
    1486: try {  
    1487: WbdProductionHelper helper = productionHelper_mall_layouts_headers_and_footers_headerxx2_405;  
    1488: String snippetVar_defaultImagePath = "/mall/widgetti/images/widget/xxfeedbackform";  
    1489: String snippetVar_selfNavpoint = "xx-home";  
    1490: String snippetVar_selfNavpointUrl = "/home";  
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this effect every page, or just some pages?

The code that asks widgets to generate code has barely changed in five years, and has generated consistent and predictable code many millions of times without problem, so I suspect the cause of this problem lies elsewhere. My guess would be one of the following:

1. The webdesign has changed, or perhaps switched to a different branch, OR
2. One of your widgets is somehow corrupting the generation process, OR
3. The system configuration (wbd.conf?) has been changed between the two generation runs you mention.

Are you building using the ToolTwist Controller, or some other method? If you are using the Controller check that the versions of your extension projects are nailed down to specific branches, and preferably a specific Git tag. If you are using Maven or some other home grown build process then check the versions and commit times in your repo logs. You might find something changed between the two generate runs.

If the problem only effects certain pages, then that is also a good starting point. Look for a widget that only exists on those pages with problems, and see if it has changed or if it's code has a dependency on any sort of external factor.

If you can reproduce the error it should be easy to track down the cause. If you can't reproduce the error then I think you need to consider whether someone has changed something either accidentally or quietly. I don't believe it likely that *everything* remained the same, but the generation process produced a different result.